# Which one to choose for Azure AD integration in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

Which library do we have to use for integrating Azure AD in an iOS app - ADAL/MSAL ? Is MSAL an advanced version of ADAL with support for personal accounts also? Which one supports SAML 2.0 protocol ?

Comment: Did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp ?

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @DeviyaniSwami So both ADAL & MSAL libraries doesn't support SAML protocol. Is my understanding correct on this ?

Comment: @TonyJu Thanks for replying Tony..what I want to confirm is whether I can use ADAL library for integrating with my app and also does it support SAML protocol ?

Comment: @subin272 Yes, v1.0  does support saml 2.0 protocol. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-protocol-reference

Comment: @TonyJu So I should refer to this sample right https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios

Comment: @subin272 Yes, you can. Here is another sample. https://github.com/azureadquickstarts/nativeclient-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSAL works with the AzureAD V2 endpoint, whereas ADAL works with the AzureAD V1 endpoint. You can find the difference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison). Yes, MSAL allows personal accounts to sign in.

If you're migrating or updating an application that relies on SAML, you can't use Microsoft identity platform(MSAL). Instead, refer to the [Azure AD v1.0 guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview).